# How to change image names quickly in a folder with php by using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have an image folder and in it, there are nearly 200 images. My image names are :

```
101.png
102.png
103.png
(it continues until 300.png)
```

These images are the images which my books have in mysql database. For example;

```
id | book_name
101| aaaaa
102| bbbbb
```

So, I want to change my image names as book names. That is to say, the image name of "aaaa" book will be aaaa.png instead of 101.png. Is there any quick way to do this?
Thanks....

Comment: What if 2 books have the same name?

Comment: there are not same book names in my database.

Comment: do you need to change the actual filenames or do you want to just display the url as aaaa.jpg as you could use rewriterule to do this

Comment: I need to change actual file names, not urls.

Comment: despite all of these great questions, the poster has not yet said if they've tried anything, and if so, what it is they've tried

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb', 'myuser', 'mypass');
$books = $db->query('SELECT * FROM books');
$images_folder = '/var/bookimages/';

foreach ($books as $book) {
    $old_image_file = realpath($images_folder.$book['id'].'.jpg');
    if ($old_image_file) {
        $clean_book_name = filter_var($book['book_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
        $new_image_file = realpath($images_folder).$clean_book_name.'.jpg';
        rename($old_image_file, $new_image_file);
    }
}
```

- [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) handles interactions with the database. It's the preferred way of connecting to databases on PHP.
- The `rename()` function only works if the origin and destination names are files in the same disk. On your case, this should work fine.
- I've used a very simple query on the database. Usually, you'll want to limit it and specify the columns you want.
- I'm using `filter_var` to check if the name in the database is valid. This is a security measure. If the database has a file name containing '../' the file won't do bad things. This is necessary because `rename()` can also move files and someone may exploit it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof of concept. It should get you started.

```
$books = array('100' => 'grapes of wrath', '101' => 'where the red fern grows');

echo '<pre>'; print_r($books); echo '</pre>';

foreach($books AS $key => $value){
    $current_image = $key.'.jpg';
    $new_image = $value.'.jpg';
    echo $current_image.' & '.str_replace(" ", "_",$new_image).'<br />';
    //rename($current_image, $new_image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be bad practice to change images names to names of books.
What if your names will have special symbols? What if name is too long?

It's much more simple and universal solution to use ID's.

Comment: poster seems to not care that is a bad idea

Comment: After I named some disadvantages of using real book's names, may be he will think again :-)

Comment: for books, it is may be bad idea but it could be useful something else. Important thing is to undrstand basics.